Split a array javascript using regular expressions
I am trying to split this array in 2 or 3 parts and stuck. This is what I have so far, if I use one of the splice lines it works but if I use all to test cases then does not.  I want to:

grab everything before the operator and combine it into one number - variable
grab everything after the operator and combine it into one number - variable
grab the operator and give it a separate variable

const re = /^(\+\/\-\*)$/

let store1 = ["7", "1", "+", "9", "6"]
store2 = store1.splice(0, store1.indexOf(re));

// This does not work all at once, only if one line is uncommented
//store2 = store1.splice(0, store1.indexOf('+'));
//store2 = store1.splice(0, store1.indexOf('-'));
//store2 = store1.splice(0, store1.indexOf('*'));
//store2 = store1.splice(0, store1.indexOf('/'));

console.log(store1)
console.log(store2)

I tried what I posted in the code, I have tried turning the array.toStrings() and looping through but cant make sense of it yet.

I'm not sure what array.toStrings() is, but perhaps you mean store1.join("").

You do not split arrays with regex. You can split strings with regex.

what is your expected result

Given the format of the "array" looks like a string, it might be easier to parse this as a string using a slightly altered regex.
To convert an array to a string without separators, use .join("")
const re = /(\+|\-|\*)/;
let store1 = ["7", "1", "+", "9", "6"];

console.log(store1.join("").split(re))

As needed, you can then use destructuring assignments (SO answer) to convert the array to distinct variables (assuming you only have a simple num op num):
let [ v1, op, v2 ] = [...store1.join("").split(re)]

Snippet:


const re = /(\+|\-|\*)/;
let store1 = ["7", "1", "+", "9", "6"];

let [ v1, op, v2 ] = store1.join("").split(re);

console.log(v1, op, v2);




You can just use let [ v1, op, v2 ] = store1.join("").split(re); without spreading it into an array btw

@NickParsons thanks for the tip - first time I've used that let [ .. ] to assign multiple variables.  Now you say "into an array" it's obvious - no need to convert an array into an array.  Ta

I appreciate the help @fdomn-m . I will need to spend some time studying the use of regex and how your used the join split to solve this.

.join(separator) will convert an array to a string, by using "" it means there's no separator.   The regex is just "one of + - or * in any position", the \\ is there because they otherwise have meanings in a regex.
